# Нормально ли с точки зрения хорошей архитектуры иметь метод на 50-60+ строк?

Tags: java, json, jackson

Есть метод, на вход которого приходит список Json - строк. Из них нужно распарсить  данные, преобразовать их к рабочему виду и склеить в один текст, который уже уйдёт на фронт. Использую Jackson, привожу Json к дереву, из дерева достаю нужное. 
Нормально ли с точки зрения хорошей архитектуры всё это делать в одном методе, который будет содержать минимум 50-60+ строк, либо нужно как-то красиво разделить задачу на несколько методов и при этом лишний раз не передавая кучу данных между методами?

P.S Прислушался к ответчикам и разделил функционал на два метода: один отвечает за парсинг, а другой - за форматирование. 
P.S.S Не вижу смысла редактировать вопрос, так как изначально и не предполагалось найти железную истину, но хотелось услышать мнение опытных разработчиков. Всем спасибо!

Comment: Странный вопрос, тс сам с собой поговорил, а о том, что это нормально или нет - то ответ скорее в том, нормально ли для вас в одном файле разбираться или нет, вы должны решить сами.

Comment: Пока метод находится на одном экране(80 строк) и выполняет одну задачу - согласно "правилу хорошего кода" инкапсуляция не требуется.

Comment: @ВладимирКлыков А при чем тут инкапсуляция?

Comment: @m.vokhm потому что один из побочных эффектов - сокращение кода отдельных методов.

Comment: @ВладимирКлыков, у вас на экране (в рабочем окошке) 80 строк?

Comment: Все зависит не от мнения авторитетов (*см. ответ ниже*), а от здравого смысла. Если метод последовательно выполняет взаимосвязанные по данным действия на одном логическом уровне, то вполне нормально (например, программируя какое-то устройство вы прописываете десятки конфигурационных регистров, вызывая для каждого определенную функцию и в силу каких-то обстоятельств передаваемые аргументы нельзя объединить в общую таблицу)

Comment: @avp Дома меньше, на работе - больше =) 
https://yadi.sk/i/yOIzZZdnDpglMQ

Comment: @avp Кстати, верно. Добавлю это соображение к своему ответу

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Р. Мартин в своей книге "Чистый код" пишет:

> Желательно, чтобы длина функции не превышала 20 строк

М. Фаулер в книге "Рефакторинг" называет длинные методы в числе основных признаков "кода с душком" и советует делать их как можно короче. Он пишет

> Мы придерживаемся эвристического правила, гласящего, что если ощущается необходимость что-то прокомментировать, надо написать метод. В таком методе содержится код, который требовал комментариев, но его название отражает назначение кода, а не то, как он решает свою задачу. Такая процедура может применяться к группе строк или всего лишь к одной строке кода.

Лично я с ними совершенно согласен, стараюсь не писать методов длинее 10-20 строк, часто методы содержат лишь одну строку кода:

```
  exp2 = findBinaryExponent(mant10, exp10);
```

понять намного проще, чем

```
  exp2 = (long) Math.floor( exp10 * LOG2_10 + log2(mant10) );  // find binary exponent
```

Метод `findBinaryExponent()` из первого примера кода содержит лишь вычисление выражения, приведенного во втором примере.

Фаулер описывает конкретные приемы изменения кода, позволяющие улучшать качество (методы рефакторинга), напр.

> Преобразуйте фрагмент кода в метод, название которого объясняет назначение этого кода

и подробно описывает технику их исполнения, позволяющую избегать ошибок.

В обеих упомянутых книжках много полезных соображений о том, как писать код и как его улучшать, чтобы он был понятным, модифицируемым и легко сопровождаемым. Сильно рекомендую их почитать.

Современные IDE позволяют автоматизировать многие приемы рефакторинга, в т. ч. выделение фрагмента кода в отдельный метод. Советую с этими возможностями разобраться и использовать их.

За исключением очень редких, экзотических, случаев, удобочитаемость программы намного важнее, чем скорость ее выполнения. Давно сказано, что код пишется один раз, а читается многократно. Где-то мелькали результаты исследований, показавших, что программист тратит на написание нового кода во много раз меньше времени и сил, чем на чтение чужого и своего же, ранее написанного, кода. Это значит, что улучшение кода в смысле его понятности означает повышение производительности. Мой личный опыт и наблюдения вполне подтверждают это.

Однако, как верно замечено в комментариях к вопросу, никакие правила не должны отменять или заменять здравый смысл. Бывают ситуации, когда дробить длинные методы на мелкие части не только не полезно, а прямо вредно. В комментарии приведен пример программирования контроллеров, подобные ситуации также часто бывают при инициализации сложных окон в GUI.

Comment: `удобочитаемость программы намного важнее, чем скорость ее выполнения` — дополню, что в эпоху современных оптимизирующих компиляторов улучшение читаемости и повторной применимости кода практически никогда не влияет на производительность.

Answer (score 3):

Метод должен выполнять одну задачу. Так его читать и тестировать удобно. Если в нем десятки строк, значит в нем смешение функционала.

А, вообще, лучшим ответом является практика, когда через некоторое время (месяц, два, три... когда уже контекст подзабылся) поднимаешь свой старый код, и если его нужно разбирать больше (условно) 5 секунд, значит с кодом, точно не все в порядке.

Это же верно и для классов. Очень не айс потом разбирать огромные супер-классы, в которых методы "хитро" взаимосвязаны друг с другом.

Опять же, большие методы (и, как следствие, классы) - могут быть следствием попытки думать линейным алгоритмом, а не взаимодействием объектов.